# Select max value in subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, max

I have a query like below:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         centre_name, sum(qty) as number1 
     from 
         (select 
              exchange_from_centre_id as cenid, 
              count(exchange_from_centre_id) as qty
          from 
              as2.exchange
          group by 
              exchange_from_centre_id

          union all

          select 
              exchange_to_centre_id as cenid, 
              count(exchange_to_centre_id) as qty
          from 
              as2.exchange
          group by 
              exchange_to_centre_id), as2.centre c
where 
    c.centre_id = cenid
group by 
    centre_name);
```

and this is the result: Name of the centre and the number of exchange

```
Alice Springs Desert Park   1
Werribee Open Range Zoo     6
Kruger National Park        2
Johannesburg Zoo            4
Australia Zoo               2
SanWild Wildlife Sanctuary  5
```

I like to select the max value from this result (the 2nd row), beside sorting and choosing the 1st row, could anyone help me with the MAX query.

Comment: please include rdbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work

```
select * from (select centre_name, sum(qty) as number1 from 
                (select exchange_from_centre_id as cenid, count(exchange_from_centre_id) as qty
                from as2.exchange
                group by exchange_from_centre_id
            union all
                select exchange_to_centre_id as cenid, count(exchange_to_centre_id) as qty
                from as2.exchange
                group by exchange_to_centre_id), as2.centre c
where c.centre_id = cenid
group by centre_name) where number1 = (select max(number1) from (select centre_name, sum(qty) as number1 from 
                (select exchange_from_centre_id as cenid, count(exchange_from_centre_id) as qty
                from as2.exchange
                group by exchange_from_centre_id
            union all
                select exchange_to_centre_id as cenid, count(exchange_to_centre_id) as qty
                from as2.exchange
                group by exchange_to_centre_id), as2.centre c
where c.centre_id = cenid
group by centre_name));
```

Comment: you need to select from the table where the number equals to the max result from the table, but thats not very efficiant. order by and selecting the first row will be better here

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b4e/1)

I use your result query instead of the big query to simplify the sample.

I update your sample to have 2 row with max value 6.

You calculate in a select the max value, and then join to the original table to bring all row matching that value

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT MAX(Score) Score
      FROM Table1) as mV
INNER JOIN Table1 t
   ON mv.Score = t.Score
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Could you give more details?

Comment: Any reason why I didnt got the correct answer when I my answer was first?